# Sorting a Filtered Table based on data in another table

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

I have two tables (SharePoint Lists). **Employees** contains a record for each employee and general information about them. **Overtime Records** contains a record for each overtime shift worked, including the employee that worked the shift and the date. Therefore Overtime Records has a many-to-one relationship with Employees. `'Overtime Records'.Employee.Id JOINS TO Employees.ID`

I have successfully placed a text field in a custom gallery that counts the number of Overtime Shifts each employee has worked with the following code. `TimesWorked` is a Text Label object within the custom gallery.

```
TimesWorked.Text = CountRows(
   Filter(
       'Overtime Records',
       Employee.Id = ThisItem.ID
   )
)
```

My issue is in getting the gallery itself to sort by this value. Here is the `Gallery.Items` property I tried to code:

```
Gallery.Items = Sort(Employees,
    CountRows(
        Filter(
            'Overtime Records',
            Employee.Id = ID
        )
    )
)
```

This should sort by the `CountRows()` expression. ID (all caps) is a field in the Employee table. Employee.Id is a field in the Overtime Records table. I suspect there may be an ambiguity issue with which ID field I'm referencing since the Filter expression is nested within the Sort expression. It won't allow me to specify Employees.ID; I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can sort the Employees table using the CountRows, you will need to make that information available by adding a column - and no, not adding a column to the SharePoint List :)

Power Apps gives you the ability to add column to tables using the the [AddColumns Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-table-shaping)

Step by step:

1. **RenameColumns Function:** `RenameColumns(Employees,"ID", "IdentifierEmployees")`
2. **AddColumns Function:** `AddColumns(RenameColumns(Employees,"ID", "IdentifierEmployees"),"CountOfOvertime", CountRows(Filter('Overtime Records',EmployeeId = IdentifierEmployees)))`
3. **SortByColumns Function:** `SortByColumns(AddColumns(RenameColumns(Employees,"ID", "IdentifierEmployees"),"CountOfOvertime", CountRows(Filter('Overtime Records',EmployeeId = IdentifierEmployees))),"CountOfOvertime",Descending)`

Renaming the column in  step one is the way I find to work for me since the Filter part won't work if I have "EmployeeId = Id"

Hope it helps

Comment: Holy cow this is promising. I will try this tomorrow and report back!

Comment: Amazing! It worked perfectly. That was so helpful. Thank you! `RenameColumns()` is a great tip to avoid conflicting field names going forward, too!

Comment: Awesome! And yes, RenameColumns turns out to be a great way of giving more meaningful names to columns and to avoid confusion and conflicts